# XML Document SelectSingleNode returns null

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to read XML from stream reader and am also getting response XML. But when i try to read its nodes it is always returning null.

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(address);
var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
var stream = response.GetResponseStream();

if(stream != null)
{
   var xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(stream);
   var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
   xmlDocument.Load(xmlReader);
   var node = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("RateQuote");
}
```

**XML Document**

```
<RateQuoteResponse xmlns="http://ratequote.usfnet.usfc.com/v2/x1">
  <STATUS>
   <CODE>0</CODE>
   <VIEW>SECURED</VIEW>
   <VERSION>...</VERSION>
  </STATUS>
 <RateQuote>
   <ORIGIN>
     <NAME>KNOXVILLE</NAME>
     <CARRIER>USF Holland, Inc</CARRIER>
     <ADDRESS>5409 N NATIONAL DR</ADDRESS>
     <CITY>KNOXVILLE</CITY>
     <STATE>TN</STATE>
     <ZIP>37914</ZIP>
     <PHONE>8664655263</PHONE>
     <PHONE_TOLLFREE>8006545963</PHONE_TOLLFREE>
     <FAX>8656379999</FAX>
  </ORIGIN>
  <DESTINATION>
     <NAME>KNOXVILLE</NAME>
     <CARRIER>USF Holland, Inc</CARRIER>
     <ADDRESS>5409 N NATIONAL DR</ADDRESS>
     <CITY>KNOXVILLE</CITY>
     <STATE>TN</STATE>
     <ZIP>37914</ZIP>
     <PHONE>8664655263</PHONE>
     <PHONE_TOLLFREE>8006545963</PHONE_TOLLFREE>
     <FAX>8656379999</FAX>
  </DESTINATION>
     <ORIGIN_ZIP>37914</ORIGIN_ZIP>
     <DESTINATION_ZIP>37909</DESTINATION_ZIP>
     <TOTAL_COST>99.24</TOTAL_COST>
     <SERVICEDAYS>1</SERVICEDAYS>
     <INDUSTRYDAYS>1.6</INDUSTRYDAYS>
     <CLASSWEIGHT>
        <CLASS>55</CLASS>
        <ASCLASS>50</ASCLASS>
        <WEIGHT>100</WEIGHT>
        <CHARGES>0.0</CHARGES>
     </CLASSWEIGHT>
</RateQuote>
</RateQuoteResponse>
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The XML document uses the default namespace "http://ratequote.usfnet.usfc.com/v2/x1".  You need to change the `SelectSingleNode` call to use this namespace.

You need to setup a namspace manager and then supply it to `SelectSingleNode`.

```
var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("rate", "http://ratequote.usfnet.usfc.com/v2/x1");
var node = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("//rate:RateQuote", nsmgr);
```

**EDIT**
The `RateQuoteResponse` element has a default namespace `xmlns="..."`.  This means that all elements use this namespace also, unless specifically overridden.

Comment: `var node = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("//rate:RateQuote/TOTAL_COST", nsmgr);` Why this is not working? It is again throwing `null`

Comment: @SSS: You've got the same problem again - the `TOTAL_COST` element is in that namespace too. (I'm editing my answer to mention this.)

Comment: Thanks. I sometimes wonder if the people who developed these APIs have ever actually tried to use them!

Comment: Or... just forget about all these crappy namespaces and use XPath instead :) `xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode(String.Format("//*[local-name()='{0}']", nodeName));`

Comment: And this is why XML is dying and JSON is taking over. Parsing XML has always been a massive undertaking and never worth the effort...

Comment: @iGanja `System.Xml.Linq` is nice - a much well-thought-out API.

Comment: This gets me every time. Why is Microsoft's default XML API so easy to misuse and get a NULL result with no exception thrown or explanation?

Answer (score 16):

You can remove the namespace while reading the file, just disable the namespaces on the XmlTextReader:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(address);
var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
var stream = response.GetResponseStream();

if(stream != null)
{
   var xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(stream);
   xmlReader.Namespaces = false;
   var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
   xmlDocument.Load(xmlReader);
   var node = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("RateQuote");
}
```

After that you don't have to care about the namespace while using XPath / LINQ on your XML-elements.

Comment: pfff! Thank you very much! I spent 3 hours on various different solutions to finally understand that the namespacing is ruining the whole reading of the document...

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that you're asking for a `RateQuote` element without a namespace - whereas the `RateQuote` element is *actually* in the namespace with URI `http://ratequote.usfnet.usfc.com/v2/x1`.

You can *either* use an `XmlNamespaceManager` to address the namespace within your XPath, or use LINQ to XML which has very simple namespace handling:

```
var document = XDocument.Load(stream);
XNamespace ns = "http://ratequote.usfnet.usfc.com/v2/x1";
XElement rateQuote = document.Root.Element(ns + "RateQuote");
```

Personally I would use LINQ to XML if you possibly can - I find it much more pleasant to use than `XmlDocument`. You can still use XPath if you want of course, but I personally prefer to use the querying methods.

EDIT: Note that the namespace defaulting applies to child elements too. So to find the `TOTAL_COST` element you'd need:

```
XElement cost = document.Root
                        .Element(ns + "RateQuote")
                        .Element(ns + "TOTAL_COST");
```

Comment: Thanks, Can you post `LINQ` code example to select `RateQuote` node ?

Comment: @SSS: That's the code that I *have* posted - the `rateQuote` variable refers to the `<RateQuote>` element.

Comment: Thanks, xml document fails to load and it is throwing error as `No root element found` in line `var document = XDocument.Load(stream);`

Comment: @SSS: Well that suggests you've already consumed the stream. Are you trying to do this after *also* loading it into an XmlDocument?

Comment: The code i added in question alone gets that error. And am not sure what you are asking sorry

Comment: @SSS: You shouldn't be *adding* it to the previous code - it *replaces* the code where previously you were loading an `XmlDocument`... replace everything in your `if` body with the code I've gven.

Answer (score 6):

You might want to set **Namespaces** to **false** in the XmlTextReader.

So, in your code, change:

```
var xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(stream);
```

to

```
var xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(stream) { Namespaces = false };
```

With this change, you should be able to get the node you want with SelectSingleNode without having to use namespaces.

Answer (score 4):

You should also be able to do:

```
...
var node = xmlDocument["RateQuote"];
...
```

The VB syntax for that is:

```
...
Dim node as XmlNode = xmlDocument("RateQuote")
...
```