# What have I done wrong here with checking for xml nodes that don't exist?

Tags: c#, xml

My XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<bookstore xmlns="urn:newbooks-schema">
  <book genre="novel" style="hardcover">
    <title>The Handmaid's Tale</title>
    <author>
      <first-name>Margaret</first-name>
      <last-name>Atwood</last-name>
    </author>
    <price>19.95</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

My program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;

namespace MoreXMLTesting
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Create the XmlDocument.
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("newbooks.xml");

            if (doc.SelectSingleNode("/bookstore/book/title") == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Whelp, there aren't any new books");
            }
            if (doc.SelectSingleNode("/bookstore/coffee") == null);
            {
                Console.WriteLine("There ain't coffee at this joint");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I would have thought that I'd get the output of "There ain't coffee at this joint, but I also get "Whelp, there aren't any new books." What have I done wrong here with checking for xml nodes that don't exist?

EDIT:

Struggling with another aspect. What happens when there is a sub-namespace?

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<bookstore xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="C:\newbooks.xsd">
  <book genre="novel" style="hardcover">
    <title>The Handmaid's Tale</title>
    <author>
      <first-name>Margaret</first-name>
      <last-name>Atwood</last-name>
    </author>
    <price>19.95</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

Comment: Try removing single quote in xml

Comment: You need to add a namespace manager for the newbooks-schema and use that namespace manager when you query the nodes.

Comment: Add the namespace : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17161317/xml-document-selectsinglenode-returns-null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to **respect** and deal with the XML namespace in your XML document!

```
<bookstore xmlns="urn:newbooks-schema">
           ***************************
```

Try this code:

```
// Create the XmlDocument.
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

// Create the XML Namespace Manager and initialize it    
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns", "urn:newbooks-schema");

doc.Load("newbooks.xml");

// *USE* the namespace prefix as defined by your "nsmgr" in your XPath
if (doc.SelectSingleNode("/ns:bookstore/ns:book/ns:title", nsmgr) == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Whelp, there aren't any new books");
}

if (doc.SelectSingleNode("/ns:bookstore/ns:coffee", nsmgr) == null) ;
{
    Console.WriteLine("There ain't coffee at this joint");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for that! I'm just learning XML stuff as you can tell. Follow-up question. Does every XML have a namespace?

Comment: @BradB.: every XML has an *implicit* namespace - if none is presented **explicitly** - but that feels kinda like "no namespace"

Comment: Thanks, and sounds good. I've got another problem already. I've got this: <portmap xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="C:\mma\config\xsd\protocol.xsd">. How does the "xmlns:xsi" get addressed in an Xpath and AddNamespace?

Comment: Just add `nsmgr.AddNamespace("xsi", "w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");` and use the `xsi` prefix where needed

Comment: I don't know why I'm struggling with this one so much. Thank you very much for your help, and hopefully you can help a bit more. I've edited the original question to include the weird namespace items that have been dropped in my lap. I've been doing a bunch of reading, but cannot figure out how to check nodes with that odd namespace nomenclature. Only thing I've found is someone saying they shouldn't have namespaced the xml file if they weren't going to use them. Whelp, it's the file I'm stuck working with. Thank you again. Truly.