# SelectSingleNode() results in null value

Tags: xml, powershell

I readily admit that I don't understand XML but I'm trying to learn. That said, I've hit a dead end with my learning on this one particular problem.

First, I've seen the thread at this link, but its solution wasn't helpful:
[XML Document SelectSingleNode returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17161317/xml-document-selectsinglenode-returns-null)
You can see I've added some of the suggested code below and it has resulted in the same behavior.

I'm trying to append a list of printers to an XML document that looks pretty much like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<REMOTE_PRINTING_NODE>
  <PRINTING_PARAMETERS_FILE>
  </PRINTING_PARAMETERS_FILE>
  <PRINTER_MAPPINGS>
    <PRINTER_MAPPING>
      <PHYSICAL>\\Server\Printer_1</PHYSICAL>
      <LOGICAL>Printer_1</LOGICAL>
    </PRINTER_MAPPING>
    <PRINTER_MAPPING>
      <PHYSICAL>\\Server\Printer_2</PHYSICAL>
      <LOGICAL>Printer_2</LOGICAL>
    </PRINTER_MAPPING>
  </PRINTER_MAPPINGS>
</REMOTE_PRINTING_NODE>
```

And here is the code to import, append and save the XML data:

```
Install-Module PSExcel

$xml = [xml](Get-Content "C:\printer.xml")
$printerList = (Import-XLSX "C:\Printers.xlsx")

$ns = New-Object xml.xmlnamespacemanager($xml.NameTable)
$ns.AddNameSpace("x", "http://microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/GPOOperations/MigrationTable")

forEach ($printer in $printerList) {

    $mapEl = $xml.CreateElement("PRINTER_MAPPING")
    $LogEl = $xml.CreateElement("LOGICAL")
    $PhyEl = $xml.CreateElement("PHYSICAL")

    $PhyEl.AppendChild($xml.CreateTextNode("$($printer.Physical)"))
    $LogEl.appendChild($xml.CreateTextNode("$($printer.logical)"))

    $mapEl.AppendChild($PhyEl)
    $mapEl.AppendChild($LogEl)

    $mappings = $xml.SelectSingleNode("/x:REMOTE_PRINTING_NODE/x:PRINTER_MAPPINGS", $ns)
    $mappings.AppendChild($mapEl)

}
    
$xml.save("C:\printer.xml")
```

The problem I run into is with this line:

```
$mappings.AppendChild($mapEl)
```

Each iteration through the foreach loop fails to append the built XML data to the document because $mappings is null. I'm not sure where to go from here. Thanks.

Comment: try $mappings = $xml.SelectSingleNode("/REMOTE_PRINTING_NODE/PRINTER_MAPPINGS", $ns)

Comment: Why not just use the built-in PowerShell cmdlets for dealing with XML?

Comment: @Aaron That worked, thank you! Can you post an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your request, Sir.

try $mappings = $xml.SelectSingleNode("/REMOTE_PRINTING_NODE/PRINTER_MAPPINGS", $ns)

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comment.

```
Get-Command -Name '*xml*' | Format-Table -AutoSize
# Results
<#
CommandType Name          Version Source
----------- ----          ------- ------
Cmdlet      ConvertTo-Xml 3.1.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility
Cmdlet      Export-Clixml 3.1.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility
Cmdlet      Import-Clixml 3.1.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility
Cmdlet      Select-Xml    3.1.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility
#>
```

So, your post...

```
[xml]$XmlData = '
<REMOTE_PRINTING_NODE>
  <PRINTING_PARAMETERS_FILE>
  </PRINTING_PARAMETERS_FILE>
  <PRINTER_MAPPINGS>
    <PRINTER_MAPPING>
      <PHYSICAL>\\Server\Printer_1</PHYSICAL>
      <LOGICAL>Printer_1</LOGICAL>
    </PRINTER_MAPPING>
    <PRINTER_MAPPING>
      <PHYSICAL>\\Server\Printer_2</PHYSICAL>
      <LOGICAL>Printer_2</LOGICAL>
    </PRINTER_MAPPING>
  </PRINTER_MAPPINGS>
</REMOTE_PRINTING_NODE>
'

Select-Xml -Xml $XmlData -XPath "//PRINTER_MAPPINGS"
# Results
<#
Node             Path        Pattern           
----             ----        -------           
PRINTER_MAPPINGS InputStream //PRINTER_MAPPINGS
#>

(Select-Xml -Xml $XmlData -XPath "//PRINTER_MAPPINGS").Node
# Results
<#
PRINTER_MAPPING                   
---------------                   
{PRINTER_MAPPING, PRINTER_MAPPING}
#>

((Select-Xml -Xml $XmlData -XPath "//PRINTER_MAPPINGS").Node).PRINTER_MAPPING 
# Results
<#
PHYSICAL           LOGICAL  
--------           -------  
\\Server\Printer_1 Printer_1
\\Server\Printer_2 Printer_2
#>
```

So, reading in XML, and adding to a node.

```
[xml]$XmlData = Get-Content -Path 'D:\temp\printer.xml'

$XmlElementMapping = $XmlData.CreateElement('PRINTER_MAPPING')
$XmlData.REMOTE_PRINTING_NODE.PRINTER_MAPPINGS.AppendChild($XmlElementMapping)

$XmlElementPhysical = $XmlData.CreateElement('PHYSICAL')
$XmlElementPhysical.set_InnerText('\\Server\Printer_3')
$XmlElementMapping.AppendChild($XmlElementPhysical)

$XmlElementLogical = $XmlData.CreateElement('Logical')
$XmlElementLogical.set_InnerText('Printer_3')
$XmlElementMapping.AppendChild($XmlElementLogical)

$XmlData.REMOTE_PRINTING_NODE.PRINTER_MAPPINGS.PRINTER_MAPPING
# Results
<#
PHYSICAL           LOGICAL  
--------           -------  
\\Server\Printer_1 Printer_1
\\Server\Printer_2 Printer_2
\\Server\Printer_3 Printer_3
#>

$XmlData.save('D:\Temp\printer.xml')
Get-Content -Path 'D:\temp\printer.xml'
# Results
<#
<REMOTE_PRINTING_NODE>
  <PRINTING_PARAMETERS_FILE>
  </PRINTING_PARAMETERS_FILE>
  <PRINTER_MAPPINGS>
    <PRINTER_MAPPING>
      <PHYSICAL>\\Server\Printer_1</PHYSICAL>
      <LOGICAL>Printer_1</LOGICAL>
    </PRINTER_MAPPING>
    <PRINTER_MAPPING>
      <PHYSICAL>\\Server\Printer_2</PHYSICAL>
      <LOGICAL>Printer_2</LOGICAL>
    </PRINTER_MAPPING>
    <PRINTER_MAPPING>
      <PHYSICAL>\\Server\Printer_3</PHYSICAL>
      <Logical>Printer_3</Logical>
    </PRINTER_MAPPING>
  </PRINTER_MAPPINGS>
</REMOTE_PRINTING_NODE>
#>
```